# How can I keep default mode key bindings in a new mode?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, i3

I have several "lesser" modes in my i3 config, which only have a few keybindings for specific tasks. For example, Skype mode:

```
mode "skype" {
        bindsym $mod+1 exec xdotool mousemove 90 70; exec xdotool click 1
        bindsym $mod+2 exec xdotool mousemove 90 110; exec xdotool click 1
        bindsym $mod+3 exec xdotool mousemove 90 150; exec xdotool click 1
        bindsym $mod+4 exec xdotool mousemove 90 190; exec xdotool click 1
        bindsym $mod+5 exec xdotool mousemove 90 230; exec xdotool click 1
        bindsym $mod+6 exec xdotool mousemove 90 270; exec xdotool click 1
        bindsym $mod+7 exec xdotool mousemove 90 310; exec xdotool click 1
        bindsym $mod+8 exec xdotool mousemove 90 350; exec xdotool click 1
        bindsym $mod+9 exec xdotool mousemove 90 390; exec xdotool click 1
        bindsym $mod+0 exec xdotool mousemove 90 430; exec xdotool click 1

        ...
}
```

which changes Alt+numbers to switch Skype chats instead of workspaces.

However, while in Skype mode, I can no longer use the other keybindings I've set up in my .i3/config (such as Alt+hjkl, dmenu, and most notably the brightness, volume, and PrtSc keys).

I'd rather not copy every single one of the `bindsym`s and `bindcode`s from the default mode into each and every one of my other modes, which would result in an unmaintainable mess<sup>1</sup>. Is there any way to "inherit" keybindings from the default mode to another?

<sup>1: well, the hardcoded pixel values for Skype mode already *are* an unmaintainable mess, but I'd rather not make it even more so. ;)</sup>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it is clear that there is no "vanilla" i3 way to do this, I have created a [small preprocessor called i3bang](https://github.com/KeyboardFire/i3bang) that allows me to achieve this.

Simply

1. Download and set up i3bang.
2. Wrap all of your keybindings in default mode like so:

   ```
   !@<+default_keybindings
   bindsym ...
   >
   ```
3. Now include a reference to that section at the end of the mode you would like to keep default keybindings in:

   ```
   mode "skype" {
           bindsym $mod+!!1..9,0 exec xdotool mousemove 90 !<70+40*!!<0..9>>; \
                                 exec xdotool click 1
           ...
           !@default_keybindings
   }
   ```

   Since i3 (somewhat unintuitively) uses the *first* occurrence of a binding to a certain key if there are multiple bindings that use the same key, putting the reference to default_keybindings *last* means that any conflicting keybindings in your new mode will override the default.

**Full disclosure**: in case it isn't clear enough already, this is my own tool.